# Custom Authorization for processes with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a REST API that is running in a Jetty Container and secured by Spring (5.2) Security with `@EnableWebSecurity` and a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, form login and logout etc (Everything as expected, users have roles, can interact with the REST API etc). In other words: I can use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()` anywhere in my Application. Now I want to authorize specific processes/procedures. Let's asume I have some kind of nightly job, cleaning up data or exporting data to other systems running in a different Thread/Pool or someting like that. I would like to give specific processes inside of my Application a specific Security Context (without writing the Security myself)

What I tried:

Having a custom `AuthenticationManager`

```
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
        final @Qualifier("myCustomAuthenticationProvider") AuthenticationProvider myCustomAuthenticationProvider) {
    return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(myCustomAuthenticationProvider));
}
```

That custom `AuthenticationManager` will only `supports` a custom implementation of `Authentication`

```
public class MyCustomAuthenticationToken implements Authentication {
    // this class could define some static set of authorities
    // or load the them from a property or what so ever
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return whatsoever;
    }
}
```

To keep things easy, let's asume a very simple `Provider` implemenation like

```
public class MyCustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws 
         AuthenticationException {
         // creating a authentcation... 
         return aFullyPopulatedAuthenticationObject
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return aClass == null || aClass.equals(MyCustomAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

A process using this could look like this:

```
public class SomeAuthorizedProcess {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private final SomeService someServiceUsingSecurityContextHolder;

    public void doSomethingAuthorized() {
        this.authenticationManager.authenticate(new MyCustomAuthenticationToken());

        // returns null because nobody manages the context :-(
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()

        // Now I want to call services, that just use the authorizataion as if a 
        // normal user is interacting with the service (via REST API), how ever, the context
        // is here null aswell
        this.someServiceUsingSecurityContextHolder.doSomethingDependingOnGrantedAuthorities();
    }
}
```

Now my problem is, that I have, of course, no `springSecurityFilterChain` managing the `SecurityContextHolder`s content. I could set it manually, but that feels very wrong. Is there a way to do this with Spring Security? I feel like missing the point

Note: I'm not using Spring Boot, only Spring

Comment: There is nothing wrong with doing it manually. See section 'Setting the SecurityContextHolder Contents Directly' of [Technical Overview](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#technical-overview). _"In fact, Spring Security doesn’t mind how you put the Authentication object inside the SecurityContextHolder."_

Comment: Hmm, ok, thanks anyways. I may implement an aspect for this then.